# Why convert .GIF to .MP4 file using by ffmpeg on Mac OSX got .MPEG4?

Tags: osx, ffmpeg, gif

```
ffmpeg -i original.gif -r 10 outfile.mp4
```

According to command above, I've got `outfile.mp4` but when clicked to see the information of file, i see it's actually a `.MPEG4` file and the icon of file is written as M4V.

[image]
[image]

How can i use ffmpeg to convert .GIF file to get exactly .MP4 file on Mac OSX?

Answer (score 1):

You exactly got what you asked for: an `.mp4` file, which is an extension used for the container format [MPEG-4 Part 14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14). `ffmpeg` did what you asked it to do.

The MP4 files (short for MPEG-4 Part 14, often with extension `.mp4`) are recognised then by your desktop, by parsing the header, but probably not the content. The desktop therefore does not distinguish between files only containing still image data, video, audio, subtitles. It just heaps this all together as what the developers of the desktop probably did see as the most common usage (MPEG-4 Movie)

Comment: I don't know but might be something wrong with my `.mp4` file i can not put it to play on `Latex`. but someone convert for me on Windows machine, it's work. The same `.mp4` but just different way to convert. then why i said something wrong with `ffmpeg` on Mac.

Comment: Now, My problem is solved by convert `GIF -> FLV` then convert `FLV -> MP4` using by `ffmpeg`. Mention that `GIF -> MP4` doesn't work with Latex.

Comment: @terces907 how is it solved? It doesn't show as an MPEG4 file anymore?

Comment: NOPE, all are the same! just size is difference. 221KB for (`GIF -> MP4`), 139KB for (`GIF -> FLV -> MP4`). I have no idea now that why it work.